# GROUP BY day in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to Postgres. I have a table that looks like this:

```
User
----
id (int)
createdOn (bigint)
isDeleted (boolean)
```

The createdOn represents the number of milliseconds since EPOCH. I'm trying to figure out how many users were created on each day that have an isDeleted flag of 0. I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', u.createdOn) AS "Day" , count(*) AS "No. of users"
FROM User u
WHERE u.isDeleted = 0 
GROUP BY 1 
ORDER BY 1;
```

How do I create this query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not say what does not work but I guess it is the `date_trunc` function

```
select
    date_trunc('day', to_timestamp(createdOn)) as "Day",
    count(*) as "No. of users"
from User
where isDeleted = 0
group by 1
order by 1;
```

Comment: It doesn't show the count per day. It just shows one single day.

Comment: @user70192 Post some data and the table schema: `\d the_table`.

Comment: @user70192 New fix (guessed). If it is seconds in instead of milliseconds then there is no need to divide by 1,000